# JavaScript eval alternative

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I have a calling object:

```
var callingObj = { fun: myroot.core.function1,
                   opts: { one: "abc",
                           two: "car",
                           three: "this.myattr1" } };
```

At a later time, the function of the "fun" attribute should be called. The parameters for this function call should be from the attribute "opts". It is very important, that the variable "three" should have the value of this.myattr1 AT THE TIME OF CALLING THE FUNCTION!

I know I could do something like this:

```
// inside a for loop which is processing the opts attributes
if (attrValue.indexOf("this.") == 0) { 
  value = eval(attrValue);​​​​​​​​​​   
  paramsObj[attr] = value;
  // instead of eval I could use
  helpval = attrValue.substring(5);
  value = this[helpval];
  paramsObj[attr] = value;
}
else {
  paramsObj[attr] = attrValue;
}
```

But is there a possible implementation, where I do not have to inspect and search for "this" in "attrValue" and react to that?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Update:
attrValue is in this case "abc", "car" or "this.myattr1". paramsObj is the parameter object for the function call.

I have put this.myattr1 in a string because I did not know any other possibility to say "this, but this at a later time".

this and myroot.core.function1 are not the same!

Comment: what exactly is `attrValue` and `paramsObj`?

Comment: Is 'myroot.core' and 'this' point to same object?

Comment: attrValue is in this case "abc", "car" or "this.myattr1". paramsObj is the parameter object for the function call.

Comment: Have you tried using function.apply?

Comment: @raghavv I'm not sure that would help with evaluating the string.

Comment: @alnorth29: It would if this points to 'myroot.core'. In that case the attr can be passed just by name.

Comment: @WolfgangAdamec Do you want to get the value `this.myattr1` from the `this` object when the `callingObj` is created or from the `this` object when the "processing the opts attributes" code-block is being evaluated? I understand you want to get the latest value, just trying to figure out from which source / scope you want it...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
var callingObj = { 
    fun: myroot.core.function1,
    opts: [
        {value: "abc"},         // `value` for literals
        {value: "car"},
        {link: "myattr1"}       // `link` for local vars on `this`
    ]
};
```

In use:

```
// resolve args:
var opts = callingObj.opts,
    args = [],
    i = 0,
    max = opts.length;

for (; i < max; i++) {
    args.push(opts[i].link ? this[opts[i].link] : opts[i].value);
}

// apply with local scope
var result = callingObj.fun.apply(this, args);
```

This would work with a function that expects 3 arguments, not a single `Object` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like jQuery's [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function to do what you need. Your explanation is good - it is `this` but at a later time and another scope.

```
var callingObj = { 
    fun: myroot.core.function1,
    opts: { one: "abc",
            two: "car",},
    getVarCallback: $.proxy(this, 'getAttr1'),
};
```

So rather than passing in the parameter as it is now, we create a `proxy` function that knows what the scope of `this` is for the function to call later.

The function getAttr1 would just return the current value of myAttr1 from whichever object it is defined in.

Then to call the function just do:

```
var currentValue = callingObject.getVarCallback();

callingObj.fun(
    callingObj.opts.one,
    callingObj.opts.two,
    currentValue
);
```

That is a very clean way of doing what you're after. You could also do the equivalent yourself by setting it up as:

var callingObj = { 
        fun: myroot.core.function1,
        opts: { one: "abc",
                two: "car",},
        caller: this,
        attrFunctionName: 'getAttr1'),
    };

and then to call it:

```
var attrFunction = callingObject.attrFunctionName;

var currentValue = callingObject.caller.attrFunction();
```

However jQuery proxy is a really clean way of doing it, as the function that is handling the callback, doesn't have to be aware if the data it's using is coming from an object or from a plain function, which makes the code be a lot more maintainable.

Comment: Hello Danack! $.proxy is a very interesting approach!